# jQuery: addClass only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an `addClass` and `removeClass` function running on window resize, using an if else statement. The markup is as follows:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  resize();
});

//Every resize of window
$(window).resize(function() {
  resize();
});

//Dynamically assign height
function resize() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
    var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
        windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        windowHeight = windowWidth / 1.7777;

        var loadwindowHeight = $(window).height(),
            loadspriteHeight = $('.spritespin-canvas').height();

            if(loadspriteHeight < loadwindowHeight) {
                $('.spritespin-canvas').addClass('height');
            } else {
                $('.spritespin-canvas').removeClass('height');
            }

}
```

The only problem is, when you resize the window, it keeps repeatedly adding and removing the class, it it possible to run the `addClass` and `removeClass` functions once? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use hasClass('height') to check https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Comment: use **$(window).one('resize',func..** instead of **$(window).resize(func..**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/).

```
var hasHeightClass = $('.spritespin-canvas').hasClass('height');
if (loadspriteHeight < loadwindowHeight && !hasHeightClass) {
    $('.spritespin-canvas').addClass('height');
} else if (hasClass) {
    $('.spritespin-canvas').removeClass('height');
}
```

Comment: @JSG Fixed. Thanks!